# Authorizing with Facebook API and login/logout

Tags: php, facebook

I have the following script for login/logout:

```
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = 'xxx';
        $config['secret'] = 'xx';
        $config['cookie'] = true; // optional
        $facebook=new Facebook($config);
        $user=$facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) 
        {
            //echo "Authorized";
            $logout_url=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
            header("Location: ".$logout_url);
        }
        else 
        {
            //echo "Not authorized";
            $login_url=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
            header("Location: ".$login_url);
        }
```

It works good for loginning, but I have some problem with registration: when I authorize successfully and I must see the window for logout but instead that my browser will be loaded and I will se the error Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). What is the problem? Thank you

UPDATED:

```
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = '436058296415139';
        $config['secret'] = '50c4ec9a2a565085e8a2e73cd0433111';
        //$config['cookie'] = true; // optional
        $facebook=new Facebook($config);
        $user=$facebook->getUser();
        $data=array();
        if ($user) 
        {
            //echo "Authorized";
           $data['url']=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
           $data['title']='For logout';
        }
        else 
        {
            //echo "Not authorized";
            $data['url']=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
            //header("Location: ".$login_url);
            $data['title']='For login';
        }
        echo '<a href="'.$data['url'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no user, you send him to the login dialog (where he logs in, and is redirected to your app).

After that, there is a user, so you immediately send him to the logout URL (which logs him out, and redirects him back to your app).

After that … repeat from start.

Comment: You are right. I have updated my code, but it still works good for logging and doesn't work for logout. Please, tell me, where have I made a mistake?